# best way to make spring app pinging different urls?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to create spring program that basically pings different URLs and returns to json their http status code. I know how to check the connection in java using HttpURLConnection but I'm not sure what's the preferred way for REST service to do it. I'm new to this so any point guidance in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using spring-web, then you can inject an instance of `RestTemplate` into your service and call its `getForEntity` method.  It returns a `ResponseEntity`

Something like this...

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

....

public void myServicePinger() {
   HttpStatus statusCode = restTemplate.getForEntity("someUrl", String.class).getStatusCode();

   log.info(statusCode);
}
```